# knowing user refresh the page, web stats

Tags: php, mysql, web-statistics

hiks ... im stack again ...

I try to make a simple visitor statistic, and i have a problem.

How to make the statistic don't update if user refresh the page ?

here my snippet

```
public function saveData($sid)
{
    global $database;

    $reff = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $referrer = isset($reff['host']) ? $reff['host'] : 'direct';
    $own = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    if($referrer!=$own){
        $ip       = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $time     = time();
        $page     = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $add = $database->tableAdd("eu_shop_pageview", "shop_id, ip, timestamp, page, referrer", "'$sid', '$ip', '$time', '$page', '$referrer'");
    }
}
```

thanks :)

Regards, Stecy

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` after refreshing it will still show U previouse page not current

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, when I do view tracking, I have the following columns:

```
`id`
`identifier` : this is either the person's username or if they don't have an account, their IP
`date` : inserted using CURDATE()
`page_url`
```

Before adding to this table, I run the following query and if there are no rows returned, then I insert into that table to add a view to that page:

```
SELECT id FROM views WHERE identifier = '$user_id' AND date = CURDATE() AND page_url = '$url' LIMIT 1
```

You would want to change how you select the date if you want more/less than a day's timeframe for deciding to count new views.

Comment: If you have primary-key, & want the update-dt-tm, then consider this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if the IP address exist in the table within a time frame, if it does then don't enter it, just update the time. This is something for which you cant calculate the exact number, just an approximate count.